# How can I run this .vbs on another domain computer?

Tags: windows, vbscript

I wrote this VBS that shows Windows key:

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
MsgBox ConvertToKey(WshShell.RegRead("HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\DigitalProductId"))

Function ConvertToKey(Key)
Const KeyOffset = 52
i = 28
Chars = "BCDFGHJKMPQRTVWXY2346789"
Do
Cur = 0
x = 14
Do
Cur = Cur * 256
Cur = Key(x + KeyOffset) + Cur
Key(x + KeyOffset) = (Cur \ 24) And 255
Cur = Cur Mod 24
x = x -1
Loop While x >= 0
i = i -1
KeyOutput = Mid(Chars, Cur + 1, 1) & KeyOutput
If (((29 - i) Mod 6) = 0) And (i <> -1) Then
i = i -1
KeyOutput = "-" & KeyOutput
End If
Loop While i >= 0
ConvertToKey = KeyOutput
End Function
```

I need to run it on some other computers on our domain remotely and have key echoed back to me. I'm domain administrator. How can I do it?

Comment: Nothing, otherwise I wouldn't be asking would I?

Comment: I don't believe this to be a real question, because as you say, you have tried nothing.  [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1609560/how-to-run-vbs-script-from-cmd) is a question from our sister site has a question with an aswer that should answer your question.  [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/764406/how-to-allow-vb-scripts-to-run-on-an-admin-account) is a near duplicate.

Comment: @Jack - You're the domain administrator and you haven't tried any way of doing this first.... That's pretty lazy buddy. Why not try running it as a logon script for those computers?

Answer (score 1):

#### I need to run it on some other computers on our domain remotely

Execute the `.vbs` file on the remote machine using `cscript`:

```
psexec.exe \\computer -u user -p pass c:\windows\system32\cscript.exe script.vbs
```

---

#### Further reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/) - An excellent reference for all things Windows cmd line related.
- [Running vbscript with psexec?](https://serverfault.com/questions/202271/running-vbscript-with-psexec)
- [psexec](http://ss64.com/nt/psexec.html) - Execute a command-line process on a remote machine. Execute a command-line process on a remote machine.